# Gmail email check through automation (API)

Tags: java, gmail-api

In our application, some modules send email to a particular Gmail id.  Where I need to validate whether a particular email has been received in the inbox.  our framework is Selenium/Java/Maven, can you anyone suggest me good way to validate the email in Gmail.  I am thinking of doing it through Gmail API, any other thoughts would be very helpful with good references (especially how to authenticate login through script itself).  I will be having a particular sub-string of the email subject that will be received like "[TPV:XXX] email for user forgot password"...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any fully-packed API that does this, but the concept is so simple you could implement it yourself.

When a new user signs up:

- Make your backend generate a [Nonce](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_nonce)
- Store that nonce in your database, linked to the new user profile (like in a SQL database, have an User table, and a column "Nonce")
- Send an email to the new email address, containing a link to your website, with the nonce as parameter (something like `https://yourwebsite.com/verify?Nonce=....`)
- On your backend, the `verify` endpoint just checks if the Nonce exists in your user databse, and if it does, that means the user has clicked on the email link, and the email is verified

You could think about removing every user entry that has not a verified email on a daily basis, to prune spam emails.

Comment: Arthu, It's not going to be a new user signup, we will be already having a user setup an gmail account and that's the email account the system generated email will be sent...can you refer me some basic example to do it

Comment: This sentence is completely unclear to me. What email address do you want to verify ? At which point ?

Comment: Example: In my application, we have a module where users will be listed with their email address example "105984@gmail.com", whereas in another module when some form is submitted, it should trigger an email to the "105984@gmail.com" email address, so I was using selenium test until the form is submitted.  I need to verify through automation itself whether the email has been triggered and received in "105984@gmail.com" email box...

Comment: So .. you want to test automatically wether if the email your backend sent has been properly delivered to the recipient ? If that's the case, please shorten up your question and only include this as it is more specific and concise.

Answer (score 0):

I will assume you are using ["Selenium Client & WebDriver Language Bindings" for Java.](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/index.html)

Having this in mind, once you perform the form submission, all you have to do is to [query the Gmail API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/list) with your test user [authenticated](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/auth/about-auth).

To [authenticate to the Gmail API](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-api-java-client/oauth2), you can read thru [this documentation](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/java#step_1_turn_on_the).

To learn more about the [Gmali API in Java](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/), familiarize yourself with the [Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/java).